# Use button to reload page or div containing XML data consumed with ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, mobile, refresh, reload

I am working on a PhoneGap web app using a multi-page HTML document. During a page’s "pagebeforecreate", XML data is consumed with multiple ajax calls deferred in a $.when. If the user’s device cannot connect to the Internet, the page shows an error message and a button that is meant to reload the page once the user has Internet access.

The problem is the page does not reload and continues to show the error message and button. I found “reload” in the jQuery documentation and then saw a few examples of its use. Any suggestions on how to handle reloading a page?

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#ref_butn").click(function(){
      location.reload(true);
    });
  });

  function createList(categoryId, eventType) {
    $.when(
      getXMLData("video", categoryId),
      getXMLData("desc", categoryId),
      getXMLData("thumb", categoryId)
      ).done(function(videoAddress, videoDesc, videoThumb) {
        //builds line items and appends to targetoutputList like in .fail function below
        createLineItem(videoAddress, videoDesc, videoThumb, eventType);
      }).fail(function() {
        var targetoutputList = "#outputList" + eventType;
        var errorLineItems = [];
        errorLineItems.push('<li><h2>Try again.</h2><p>Cannot load list.</p>
           <button id="ref_butn">Refresh the page!</button></li>');
        $(targetoutputList).append(errorLineItems).listview("refresh");
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this because it might now regonize the window element:

```
$(document).one("pageinit", function() {

    $("#ref_butn").click(function(){
       window.location.href = "mypage.html";
    });

});
```

Comment: I tried that and no change. Is the click event defined in the correctly for jQueryMobile? I am a bit confused with the changes. From what I have been reading, I should not use the $(document).ready. Instead use $(document ).on('pagecontainerbeforeshow' function(event) {. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes you are, mobile loads dom and others bit differently. jQuery mobile docs recommend mobileinit but $(document).one("pageinit", function() {}); should work in all cases

Comment: OK, this is where i get confused. I am using query.mobile-1.4.3. From what I have read pageinit was deprecated in 1.4. Does that mean I should not use pageinit?

Comment: The code did not work. I kept digging around for code ideas. I found that adding data-ajax="false" to the any one of the three unordered lists or on the button to refresh makes it works. Any idea why?

Comment: Does it work like that? If you use data-ajax="false" for me it would seem they stop working. I think the issue is in something else here. If you put simple alert in in #buttonID.click function does it pop up?

Comment: When I added the alert I found that it is working inconsistently. I am simply trying to accomplish a page reload from a button click, including a new ajax call to consume data that did not work - like if the device did not have an Internet connection. How would you handle that? Remember this is a multi-page html file.

Comment: Can you put your work up to the jsfiddle? Something is not right there.. this should be simple enough

Comment: Or you can try plain js link to the same page. I updated the answer